# nodejs get latest file in a directory from a cloned git repository

Tags: node.js, git, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to get the latest added files in a directory in a newly cloned git repository.

what I have tried :

```
const getMostRecentFiles = (dir, numberOfFiles) => {
  const files = orderReccentFiles(dir);
  return files.length ? files.slice(0, numberOfFiles) : undefined;
};
const orderReccentFiles = (dir) => {
  return fs.readdirSync(dir)
    .filter((file) => fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isFile())
    .map((file) => ({
      file,
      ctime: fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).ctime
    }))
    .sort((a, b) => b.ctime.getTime() - a.ctime.getTime()).map(file => "tests/" + file.file);
};
tests = getMostRecentFiles('./tests', numberOfFiles)
```

this works completely fine, but when I run a bitbucket pipeline, it clones the repo and then gets the file.
it seems to get random files every time and I think there should be a way to get the latest added files but I cannot figure out how.
I also used lstatsync and it gives the same behavior.

Comment: Hint: Git doesn't preserve/restore access/create/modification times. In a pipeline on a fresh clone **all files are current**.

Comment: @phd I am aware of this,
I think I should use something git log for a specific git ls-list , but I am not so sure

Comment: I have [a script in Python](https://git.phdru.name/?p=git-scripts.git;a=blob;f=set-commit-date.py) that restores timestamps from commit times.

Comment: that's awesome, I did something like that in JS too. 

but my use case is that I wanted developers to run newly added tests without the need to search for their names , but this script actually takes time and would bore people more than just grapping the names from the git diff.

I think I will just close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git doesn't preserve/restore access/create/modification times. In a pipeline on a fresh clone all files are current.